# Javascript confirm in firefox responsive design mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a JavaScript 'confirm' window in my page and since I would like to use the page also on mobile devices I am trying to debug it in FireFox RDM. The 'Confirm' window doesn't show up while in RDM mode is turned on so my question is "is it going to show up on mobile devices?"

I have found an old note that RDM has this bug but I also have no way of checking if confirm works as intended on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm Window does work on Mobile devices, given the mobile browser that you're using follows ECMAScript 5.1 standards. All the major browser such as Firefox and Chrome would support it but can't say about UCWEB and other browsers.

Also, the reason you might not be able to see the confirm window in RDM, might be a problem with your CSS and not JS at all. From the minimal info that you provided, I think the issue is with your CSS or JS code but can't be sure as you haven't shared the code here.

Comment: I just apply some common sense to read the question carefully that the OP has posted.
**'Confirm' window doesn't show up while in RDM mode is turned on**
Clearly means that the code doesn't work in RDM mode only and works fine in normal mode. Also read my answer before replying. **Also, the reason you might not be able to see the confirm window in RDM, might be a problem with your CSS and not JS at all.** Clearly tells that problems might be with CSS.

Comment: Also about the comment thing! Don't be over competitive here, we all want to solve the OPs problem, and my answer does that by giving a better insight of the problem, better knowledge of the exact problem OP might be dealing with and not providing multiple plugins and options just to confuse the OP btw.

Answer (score 1):

There's bugs in Firefox RDM having to do with alert(), with some comments going back 2 years. See [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1273997), and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1336435).

console.log() still works, so you can use that for troubleshooting.

Alternatively you could try making your own pop-up in place of alert().

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of FF, rdm mode is different, and as you haven't specified the source of the note, the bug may be in the older version. RDM has a newer version from FF v52 and upwards.

There are other ways to test the appearance in mobile devices however. I would recommend [Quirktools Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) as an online tool for testing your page at different resolutions as it enables users to test sites at mobile/tablet/desktop and larger resolutions.

You could also install a window-resizer as an extension to your browser. This will simulate the appearance of a mobile and you can test it that way. [Chrome have one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) (that I use) but there's similar available in FF extensions (try [Viewport](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/viewport/?src=search) and [Windows Resizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/window-resize/?src=search) (Firesizer doesn't seem to be supported anymore))

Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly, the bug is in the new RDM version (firefox v60 at least) :(